# Is there a way to import a JS function inside a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to create a React HOC that will apply the corresponding styles to any component pass to it.

My idea was to do something similar to this

```
// Button.css.js
const styles = {backgroundColor:"blue"}

// Button.js
const Button = (props) => <button {...props}/>

// applyStyles.js
const applyStyles = (Component) => (props) => {
   const styles = import style from `${Component.name}.css`
   return <Component {...props} style={styles} />
}
```

I know applyStyles contains invalid syntax but is just to illustrate what is what I'm trying to do.

If any of you have a way around this I will really appreciate it.

Comment: This feels like a very odd abstraction. What's wrong with simply importing styles directly into the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```js
import (`/pathTofile/${Component.name}.css`)
.then(data => {
  // rest of the code goes her
})
```

Comment: this might work but this would mean that you have to lazyload this component everytime you reuse it

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is that you use [styled-component](https://styled-components.com/) for this:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
> * {
  backgroundColor:"blue"
}`

function AppyStylesHOC(Component) {
return (props) => {
return (<Wrapper>
    <Components {...props} />
  </Wrapper>
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Button.module.css';

const Button = props => {
  return (
    <button
    className={styles.button}
    type={props.type || 'button'}
    onClick={props.onClick}
    >
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Button.module.css

```
.button {
  font: inherit;
  border: 1px solid #4f005f;
  background: #4f005f;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

App.js

```
import Button from '../Button';

...

<Button type="submit">+ Add</Button>

...
```